# Override style.css Visual Composer

Tags: css, styles

Help, please.

I am trying to decrease the padding of this particular element on mobile. It's good on web, but not on mobile. [Click here to see the photo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElZq7.png)

[This is my website.](http://docampusministry.com/)  You can see the element at the most bottom part.

This is my working code now, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
@media (min-width: 240px) and (max-width: 700px)
{
.vc_column_container .sc_testimonials_1992611863_3,
.vc_column_container .sc_testimonials_1992611863_2,
.vc_column_container .sc_testimonials_1992611863_1{
padding: 1rem 0em 2rem !important;

}

}
```

Comment: you're using `!important` a lot. bad practice. [read this](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Comment: Oh, could this be the cause? I'm just trying to override several styles, that's why.